# Looking into vectors in netbeans

Tags: c++, debugging, netbeans, vector

So, I've been debugging a program in Netbeans C++, and I need to take a good look at the contents of vectors to help me see where things went wrong. So, I went into the Variables tab to dig around. Thing is, that Netbeans (or any other IDE I've used) doesn't let me see more than the first element in a vector. Clicking all the + buttons in the variables tab under the vector variable name, all I see is a bunch of gibberish.

Is there a way for me to take a good look at the contents of vectors in the debugger? I've done so much searching, and this doesn't seem to even be acknowledges as even a thing, which confuses me.

Comment: What version of gdb / netbeans are you using? If just checked using NB 8.1 and everything works fine.

Comment: I'm using Netbeans 8.1. Also, forgot to mention that I used the Variables tab to try looking into the vectors.

Answer (score 0):

At first, you need to compile your program with correct options. I usually compile applications to debug with options `-g3 -O0`.

The picture below shows a vector `v` with its three elements.

[image: Netbeans debug screen]